# Caliburn.Micro Enum binding in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, combobox, caliburn.micro

I have an enum

```
    public enum FuelType
{
    Diesel,
    Petrol,
    E10
}
```

how can i bind this to a Combobox with Caliburn.Micro

xaml: `<ComboBox x:Name="Fuel" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3"/>`

and the Property in the ModelView:

```
        public FuelType Fuel
    {
        get { return _fuel; }
        set
        {
            _fuel = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Fuel));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Example : https://summergoat.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/enum-getvalues-markup-extension/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do this is to have a list of items and the selected item in the ViewModel. The conventions in Caliburn.Micro are set up to resolve both the `ItemsSource` (using `<x:Name>`) and the SelectedItem (using `Selected<x:Name>`).

**ViewModel:**

```
internal class FuelViewModel : Screen
{
    public FuelViewModel()
    {
        FuelType = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Fueltype)).Cast<Fueltype>().ToList();
    }

    private Fueltype selectedFuelType;

    public Fueltype SelectedFuelType
    {
        get => selectedFuelType;
        set => Set(ref selectedFuelType, value);
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Fueltype> FuelType { get; }
}
```

**View:**

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="FuelType"/>
```

**Edit:**
The reason not to do what [Sybren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2175330/sybren)'s link suggests is that it breaks MVVM principles by making the View control data. If you were to change from a simple enum backing to a database backing your View breaks. With the correct approach you can change the types in the ViewModel without touching the view at all and you can also exchange the View without breaking the ViewModel.